# Generic function to flatten a container of containers

Tags: c++, templates, generics, containers

I am trying to get a better hold on iterators and generic functions.  I thought it would be a useful exercise to write a function that converts `container1 < container2 <type> >` to `container3 <type>`.  For example, it should be able to convert `vector< deque<int> >` to `list<int>`.

I figured all the container access should be through iterators, like the functions in `<algorithm>`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// COCiter == Container of Containers Iterator
// Oiter == Output Iterator
template <class COCiter, class Oiter>
void flatten (COCiter start, COCiter end, Oiter dest)
{
    using namespace std;

    while (start != end) {
        dest = copy(start->begin(), start()->end(), dest);
        ++start;
    }
}
```

But when I try to call it in the following code:

```
int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector< vector<string> > splitlines;
    vector<string> flat;

    /* some code to fill SPLITLINES with vectors of strings */

    flatten(splitlines.begin(), splitlines.end(), back_inserter(flat));
}
```

I get a huge C++ template error message, `undefined reference to void flatten< ... pages of templates ...`

I feel like my code was too easy to write, and I must need some more stuff to ensure that the data type in the inner containers matches the data type in the output container.  But I don't know what to do.

Comment: Note that stack does not have iterators, and no begin/end functions.  If you want it to work with stacks, you will most certainly have to special case it.

Comment: That's true; I will change the question.  I don't actually need stack compatibiliy; just iterable containers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the issue. Thanks to SFINAE (Substitution failure is not an error) your compiler couldn't find the correct template because you are trying to call `operator()` on `start` by typing `start()` (probably a typo). Try this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// COCiter == Container of Containers Iterator
// Oiter == Output Iterator
template <class COCiter, class Oiter>
void flatten (COCiter start, COCiter end, Oiter dest) {
    while (start != end) {
        dest = std::copy(start->begin(), start->end(), dest);
        ++start;
    }
}
```

Comment: SFINAE does not work for substitution failures that would occur in the body of the function. It only works in the function signature (return type and parameters).

Comment: That was indeed a typo, but it turned out that I was also making the error of including my generic function prototype in a header file.  I just found out you can't do that; you have to include the whole cpp file (I think).

Answer (score 4):

`std::accumulate` can do it for you.  You need to gather up the contents of each of the inside vectors into the outside vector.

```
vector<vector<int>> v_of_v;
vector<int> v = std::accumulate(
    v_of_v.begin(), v_of_v.end(),
    vector<int>(),
    [](vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
        a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
        return a;
    });
```