# Copy vector element of a vector to another vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this vector,

```
std::vector <std::vector<std::string> > gname;

gname.push_back(std::vector<std::string>({"John","jake"}));
gname.push_back(std::vector<std::string>({"May", "harold}));
```

and I want to put all the values from gname to,

```
std:vector<std::string> cname;
```

It this possible using c++11?

Comment: It ever was possible, no matter of C++11. Or did you ask about something specific from `<algorithm>`?

Comment: yes. using algorithm library.

Comment: How about a simple `for`?

Comment: yes that can be done, but is there any one liner using c++11?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6404856/1062948) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one liner. Nothing fancy, but it's readable...

```
for (auto& vec : gname) { cname.insert(cname.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Karolys fine one-liner. Here is one using `<algorithm>`

```
std::for_each(gname.begin(), gname.end(), 
        [&cname](const std::vector<std::string>& stuff){
    cname.insert(cname.end(), stuff.begin(), stuff.end());});
```

Debatable if it qualifies as a one-liner though.