# How to turn 2d array into a min heap using C++ built-in function?

Tags: c++

How can I turn this 2d array into mean heap comparing `arr[i][0]` with `arr[i+1][0]`(i is the index of the array)? I tried but it's not working.

```
vector<vector<int>> arr = {{10, 2}, {4, 10}, {1, 4}, {11, 2}};

auto comp = [](int a, int b){
 //this function will return true if a[0] is less than b[0].
    return a[1] < b[1];
};

make_heap(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comp);
```

Comment: What are `i+` and `j+` supposed to mean? `++` i.e. next element, maybe?

Comment: I meant i wanna compare with arr[0][0] with arr[1][0]?

Comment: `i+` is meaningless syntax. Do you mean `i+1`?

Comment: I corrected my question.

Comment: How do you want to compare `{10, 2}` with `{4, 10}`? What's the expected result of `{10, 2} < {4, 10}`? Do you want to compare the arrays or the elements in the inner arrays? Please provide the expected result of your code.

Comment: @jabaa Why are you even comparing `{10, 2}` with `{4, 10}` when the question states a comparison between two _elements_ of the 2-d array and not **pairs** ?

Comment: @Zoso because the lambda `fn` compares the arguments `a` and `b` and `make_heap` is called on vectors of vectors of ints. The lambda is called with two vectors as arguments. `auto fn = [](vector<int> a, vector<int> b)` with operator `<` for `vector<int>` would at least solve the syntax error but probably not yield the expected result.

Comment: "I tried but it's not working." <- not a problem description. Why is it not working? What does it do? Why is that wrong?

Comment: It seems you want to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404856/generic-function-to-flatten-a-container-of-containers) the nested vector and call `make_heap` on the result.

Comment: I still don't understand whether you want a heap of integers, a heap of vectors, or a heap of pairs. Also, do you intend for the different vectors to grow and shrink? For the values to change? It may also be helpful to describe the wider scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you can use [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) ***i.e***:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr = {{10, 2, 0}, {4, 10, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {11, 2, 1}};

priority_queue <int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;

for(const auto& i : arr)
{
    for(const auto j : i)
    {
        pq.push(j);
    }
}

while (!pq.empty())
{
    cout << pq.top() << " ";
    pq.pop();
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 10 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

First you could flatten the vector. I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404886/15388024:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// COCiter == Container of Containers Iterator
// Oiter == Output Iterator
template <class COCiter, class Oiter>
void flatten (COCiter start, COCiter end, Oiter dest) {
    while (start != end) {
        dest = std::copy(start->begin(), start->end(), dest);
        ++start;
    }
}
```

Then you can apply `make_heap` with your comparison:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr = {{10, 2}, {4, 10}, {1, 4}, {11, 2}};
vector<int> flatArr;
flatten(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(flatArr));

auto fn = [](int a, int b){
    return a < b;
};

make_heap(flatArr.begin(), flatArr.end(), fn);
```

An example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <class COCiter, class Oiter>
void flatten (COCiter start, COCiter end, Oiter dest) {
    while (start != end) {
        dest = std::copy(start->begin(), start->end(), dest);
        ++start;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr = {{10, 2}, {4, 10}, {1, 4}, {11, 2}};
    std::vector<int> flatArr;
    flatten(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(flatArr));

    auto fn = [](int a, int b){
        return a > b;
    };

    std::make_heap(flatArr.begin(), flatArr.end(), fn);
    
    for (const auto el : flatArr) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

with output:

```
11 10 10 2 1 4 4 2 // with heap property flatArr[(i + 1) / 2 - 1] >= flatArr[i]

//       11
//      /  \
//    10    10
//    /\    /\
//   2  1  4  4
//  /
// 2
```

Change the comparison function to

```
auto fn = [](int a, int b){
    return a > b;
};
```

to get a min heap

```
1 2 4 2 10 4 11 10 // with min heap property flatArr[(i + 1) / 2 - 1] <= flatArr[i]

//        1
//      /   \
//     2     4 
//    / \   / \
//   2  10 4  11
//  /
// 10
```